# Whether code is read from top to bottom

Tags: c, pointers, crash

I am creating a program in c which is based on a linked list, where every node (of struct) holds an integer and a pointer to the next node.

I use dynamic allocation (malloc) and deallocation (free) as new nodes are added and old nodes are deleted.

when a node is deleted a function named **delete** is called.

I discovered that the program crashes sometimes when this delete-function is called and I KNOW that its something with the pointers in the method but I dont know WHERE in the code (row number) and WHY this happends.

I am used to high-level languages such as Java and I am used to encircle the problem by putting print-syntax at certain places in the method just to reveal WHERE it crashes. 
I thought I could do the same with c and with pointer because to my knowledge I beleive the code is read from top to bottom that is 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. (maybe interrupt handlers behave another way?)

So in this function named **delete** *I have gone so far by putting this printf() at the very beginning of the delete-function - and all the same the program crashes.*

***So my Question - is it really possible that its some syntax in the delete-function (when I loop pointers for instance) that causes the crash WHEN not even the printf() is printing?***

Am I wrong when I believe that the program is executed from to to bottom  - that is 1, 2, 3 ....

You can se my printf-function in the very beginning of delete-function

And by the way - how could I solve this problem when I get this cryptic crash message from windows? See the bitmap!!

Greatful for answers!!!

```
 int delete(int data) {
            printf("IN THE BEGINNING OF DELETE!!!");
    int result = 0;
    if (queueref.last != NULL) { 

        node *curr_ptr;
        node *prev_ptr;
        node *temp_ptr;

        if (queueref.first->data == data) { 
            temp_ptr = queueref.first;
            queueref.first = queueref.first->next;
            destroy_node(temp_ptr);
            result = 1;
            if (queueref.first == NULL) {
                queueref.last = NULL;
                puts("queue is now empty!!!");
            }
        } else { 
            prev_ptr = queueref.first;
            curr_ptr = queueref.first->next;
            printf("prev_ptr: %d\n", prev_ptr);
            printf("curr_ptr: %d\n", curr_ptr);

            while(curr_ptr != NULL) {
                if (curr_ptr->data == data) {
                    result = 1;
                    if (curr_ptr->next != NULL) { 
                        temp_ptr = curr_ptr;
                        destroy_node(temp_ptr);
                        prev_ptr->next = curr_ptr->next;
                    } else {
                        temp_ptr = curr_ptr;
                        queueref.last = prev_ptr;
                        prev_ptr->next = NULL;
                        destroy_node(temp_ptr);
                    }
                }
                curr_ptr = curr_ptr->next; 
                prev_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Common mistake, here's the deal. This

```
        printf("IN THE BEGINNING OF DELETE!!!");
```

needs to be

```
        printf("IN THE BEGINNING OF DELETE!!!\n");
                                             ^^ note the newline
```

The reason is because stdio does not flush stdout until it sees a newline. If you add that newline, you should see the printf when the code enters the function. Without it, the program could crash, the stdout buffer would not have been flushed and would not see the printf.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have lots of implementation flaws. As a general advice I would recommend using some standard well-tested queue support library and static code analyzers (in this case you would even find dynamic analyzer valgrind very helpful, I guess).

For example, if implementation of **destroy_node(ptr)** is equivalent to **free(ptr)**, then your code suffers from referencing destroyed data (or ,in other words, garbage) in this code snippet:

```
        while(curr_ptr != NULL) {
            if (curr_ptr->data == data) {
                result = 1;
                if (curr_ptr->next != NULL) { 
                    temp_ptr = curr_ptr;
                    destroy_node(temp_ptr);
                    prev_ptr->next = curr_ptr->next; //<- curr_ptr is still in stack 
                                                     //or register, but curr->next 
                                                     //is garbage 

                    // what if curr_ptr is first node? did you forget to update queueref.first?
                } else {
                    temp_ptr = curr_ptr;
                    queueref.last = prev_ptr;
                    prev_ptr->next = NULL;
                    destroy_node(temp_ptr);
                }
                // if you you need to destroy only one node - you can leave the loop here with break;
            }
            curr_ptr = curr_ptr->next;   /// assigning garbage again if node is found 
            prev_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
```

The reason why using destroyed data can work in * most * (if I can say that, basically this is unpredictable) cases is that the chances that this memory can be reused by other part of program for dynamically allocated data can vary on timings and code flow.

PS

Regarding cryptic messages in the Windows box - when program crashes OS basically generates crashdump and prints registers (and dumps some relevant memory parts). Registers and memory dumps can show the place of crash and immediate register/stack values but you have to now memory map and assembler output to understand it. Crashdump can be loaded to debugger (WinDbg) together with unstripped binary to check stactrace and values of local variables at the moment of crash. All these I described very very briefly, you could find tons of books / guides searching for "windows crash or crashdump analysis"